# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. I have two tables named as Category and Product. Product table has foreign key which CategoryID. I am able to display category on a page. Lets take one example. I have two categories named Mobiles and Computers. When I click in Computer, I would like to display products related to Computer Category.

I have attached codes. Kindly, help me with this.

```
 public ActionResult ProductList(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(product);
    }
```

Here is model: `@model IEnumerable<ReSale.Models.Product>`
I am using IEnumerable. I am getting above error.

Comment: You passing a single `Product` to a view expecting a collection of `Product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return a single result with IEnumerable model, that's the reason you are getting this error. Try this approach:

```
var products = db.Products.Where(pr => pr.Id == id)
                      .Take(1)
                      .ToList();

return View(products);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` Add this line to your entity constructor

```
 public PlatformEntities()
            : base("name=PlatformEntities")
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
```

[Working With Proxies in Entity Framework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/working-with-proxies-in-entity-framework/)